# How to add notes functionality in myApp in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to add notes functionality in myApp in iphone so that whenever i would open that notes in future,I would get that along with the date and time of writing that note.

Edit-1:
I want to make notes in my application. I also want to add edit functionality in that notes so that whenever i will open that in future I would be able to edit that and store that for the future with time and date of editing that notes.So i want to make list of the notes which i would make for myself in my application.Please help me regarding this.Thanks in advance and ask whatever u want to give the answer of this question.

Comment: Please be more specific about what you have tried and what you have had trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do seems very simple. There are SEVERAL ways to go about doing something like that. A couple options off the top of my head:

- Create a "Note" object with properties like:

`NSString note;`

`NSDate lastEdited;`

And just store it in a file. So whenever the user modifies your data just go:

`lastEdited = [NSDate date];` To set the date to the current time.

- Personally the way I would handle this is to persist(store) the data in Core Data. That way instead of having to write your data to file each time it's modified you can save the data in one line of code:

`[myNote.managedObjectContext save:&error]`.

I hope this helps. If not there's a similar question that has already been answered here:
[Save object in CoreData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530792/save-object-in-coredata)